# Connection error when trying to connect to Cloud-sql sql-server from cloud-functions

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, sql-server-2017

I am using firebase functions to connect to cloud-sql (Micorsoft SQL Server). I tried the following to connect to SQL Server via public ip:

```
/*Tedious Start*/
var TediousConnection = require('tedious').Connection;
var TediousRequest = require('tedious').Request;
var TediousTypes = require('tedious').TYPES;
const config = {
  user: 'admin',
  password: 'password',
  server: '12.345.5.678',
  database: 'mma',
  //host: 'myproject:us-central1:my-db'
};
app.get('/mssql/', async(req, res) => {
  var sql = require('mssql');
  sql
    .connect(config)
    .then(function() {
      //6.
      var request = new sql.Request();
      //7.
      request
        .query('SET NOCOUNT ON;select * from student')
        .then(function(recordset) {
          // send records as a response
          res.send(recordset.recordset);
          sql.close();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          //8.
          console.log(err);
          sql.close();
        });
      res.end();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      //9.
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
{ ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 12.345.5.678:1433 in 15000ms
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (/srv/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:68:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (/srv/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1195:10)
    at Timeout.connectTimer.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/srv/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1157:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  originalError: 
   { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 12.345.5.678:1433 in 15000ms
    at ConnectionError (/srv/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (/srv/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1195:54)
    at Timeout.connectTimer.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/srv/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1157:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
     message: 'Failed to connect to 12.345.5.678:1433 in 15000ms',
     code: 'ETIMEOUT' },
  name: 'ConnectionError' }
```

I think the cloudfunction is unable to reach the sql server. I also tried to add the service account to have the cloudsql permissions.

I thought I was doing something wrong with my cloud functions and tried cloudsql-postgresql from cloud funtions. I am able to connect successfully to ClouSQL-postgresql from cloud function.

For e.g in case of cloudsql-postgresql, the host takes a value similar to the following using unix domain socket :

```
config.host = `/cloudsql/${process.env.CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}`;
```

In case of Cloudsql-mssql, I am providing the ipaddress for server. I do not know what I am missing. Is there a firewall issue I need to take care of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-functions):

> Cloud Functions does not support connecting to Cloud SQL for SQL
>   Server over public IP. Use private IP instead

instead you should connect directly using the private IP address and port 1433 for your instance.

Comment: Thanks! I should be blind as bat to have missed it!

Comment: To be precise, the doc is wrong. Cloud Function supports the connection to SQL server but open a Unix socket for the connexion. however, no SQL server drivers are compliant with this type of communication and thus you can't use this socket.